# How to render primitives in wireframe in Open Gl ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, render, primitive, wireframe

I can see how to render wireframe primitives in open gl. By using glPolygonMode, however this call seems to be missing from Open GL ES.

Does anyone know how to render primitives in wireframe on Open GL ES?

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It not possible to render wireframe in OpenGL ES. You can draw using lines/line strip instead of triangles but some of the lines will be lost. It's not real wireframe but it can help you see some problems. In OpenGL(not ES) you can change the way polygons are rendered using glPolygonMode, but this is not supported in OpenGL ES

Comment: This is a pretty big omission, considering wireframe mode is most useful for debugging, and portable apps are particularly difficult to debug..